# How can we Visualizing MultiDimensional data clustered?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have dataset of 100+ dimensions and I used PRECOMPUTED correlation as distance metric.

`
from sklearn import metrics

from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

af = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed').fit(my_distanceMetric_as_correlationMatrix)

cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_

labels = af.labels_
`
Now I can see the data in different clusters but I would like to visualize these clusters. So I request your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt

(ctrl-f for scikit-learn and choose the appropriate version.)

Place the downloaded file in your current working directory, and install using

```
pip install filename
```

in my case the filename is scikit_learn‑0.18.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: I did as you suggested and got the above error...(Screenshot attached in the question)